# How to read text file inside folder in c#

Tags: c#

I have 5 different text file inside the Main Folder example

c:\Main

inside Main, i have 5 file (test1.txt, test2.txt. test3.txt, test4.txt and test5.txt)

How to read the latest file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

//Get LatestFile  
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\Main");
var LatestFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
             orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
             select f).First();
//Read contents 
 string contents = File.ReadAllText(LatestFile);
```

Comment: I think you should use '\\' like "c:\\Main"

Comment: or using this one -> @

Comment: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'string[]'.  'OrderByDescending' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?

Comment: Try adding a reference to System.Core and a using directive for System.Linq and possibly System.Data.Linq.